# continiouty of maping from set back into itself.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let  $f: [a,b] \to [a,b]$ be continuous. Show that the equation $f(x) = x$ has at least one solution in $[a,b]$.
Firstly im going to assume $x \in [a,b]$ thus a is the min and b is that max or vice versa assume the first. thus x >a and $x <b$ so we can divide the interval up into $(A=[a,x) ) \cup (B=[x,b])$ then i am going to assume that f maps the interval back onto itself but doesn't not include $f(x)=x$. thus $f(A) \cap f_{closure}(B) = \phi $ and $f(B) \cap f_{closure}(A) = \phi $ thus f is not connected so clearly $f(x)=x$

im fairly certain im supposed to use the intermediate value theorem but i don't remember it. this work?

Comment: relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed_point_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are two points $x,y$ s.t. $f(x)\geq x$ and $f(y)\leq y$, then the intermediate value theorem will give a solution. Therefore, assume that $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in (a,b)$. Now think about what happens when $x\mapsto b$.

Comment: well if f(x)>x for all $x \in [a,b]$ then a isnt an element of the range of f and were done no?

Comment: You have that $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in (a,b)$. The limit when $x\to b$ must exist, by continuity, so you get $f(b)\geq b$. You also know that $f(b)\leq b$ by the definition of $f$. The case $f(x)<x$ for $x\in (a,b)$ is of course analogous.

Comment: There's no need to take limits because $f$ is defined on the closed interval $[a,b]$

Comment: Well, you have to then quote compactness and state why it means that $f(b)=b$. It's no shorter than what I wrote above and this is more from first principles, which I think is better when considering the general level of the question.